# after calculating percentage in php i got 87.555555 i wanna fixed it at 87.55

Tags: php

```
<?php 
    var $a = 85;
    var $b = 7;
    var $c = $a/$b;
    echo $c;
?>
```

Answer is `12.14285714285714`

I want to fixed it as `12.14`. How can we set two digits after decimal in PHP?

Comment: Have you tried `number_format` or any functions?

Comment: no don't tried first time i heard about number_format

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [number_format](http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php):

```
number_format($c, 2)
```

Answer (score 7):

PHP doc : [PHP Doc to round numbers](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.round.php)

In your example :

```
var $b = 7;

var $c = $a/$b;

echo round($c, 2);
```

Hope it helps

Comment: It should probably be `floor()` and not round(). Round will make 87.555 -> 87.56, Floor() makes it 87.55 as requested in the question. But who knows, it may be a typo from OP.

Comment: Yes my bad. Anyway there is some function and PHP Documentation is full of it with examples :p